# How to estimate probability of $\geq$ n type I error in multiple testing comparison?

Tags: binomial-distribution, multiple-comparisons, type-i-and-ii-errors

My question is about the calculation of the probability of making $\geq n$ type I error when $p$ independent statistical tests are made.
I can calculate the probability of $\geq 1$ type I error with the formula: $P(\geq 1) = 1-(1-\alpha)^p$ but is there a more general formula to calculate $P(\geq n)$ of making type I error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_i = I(\textrm{type I error for test} \ i)$ where $I(.)$ is the indicator function. Then we have that $X_1, \dots, X_p \sim \ iid \ Bern(\alpha)$ therefore $S := \sum X_i \sim Bin(p, \alpha)$ is the number of type I errors made. As you can see, we are relying on the fact that the tests all are independent and have the same probability of a type 1 error. Note that

$$
P(S \geq 1) = 1 - P(S = 0) = 1 - (1 - \alpha)^p
$$

as desired. Using the binomial CDF and assuming that $n \geq 1$ we can get the more general probability that you want:

$$
P(S \geq n) = 1 - P(S \leq n - 1) = 1 - \sum \limits_{i=0}^{n-1} {p \choose i} \alpha^i (1-\alpha)^{p - i}.
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer ! I'm really not used mathematical notation, could you help to translate this equation in R ? I just want to make a plot that shows the probability of type I error in function of $n$ test...

Comment: All you need is $P(S \geq n) =$ `1 - pbinom(n-1, p, alpha)` to do this. That's the function for the binomial CDF. You can also use the `lower.tail` argument in `pbinom` to avoid the `1-...` bit, although if you do so you'll need to adjust the `q` argument accordingly.